# Find Pairs in Pandas Data Frames and Perform operations on them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this. And i want to find the first pair and do operations with that.

```
        fname         lname          time of entry ............... other columns
        Adrian        Peter                 1
        Jhon          Adrian                3
        Peter         Rusk                  4
        Rusk          Anton                 10
        Gile          John                  12
        Angela        Gomes                 13
        Gomes         Angela                14
```

Now i want something like this where culprit is a value that is both in fname and lname. if for example both values are in fname and lname as the Angela Gomes case below then the culprit has to have one line with Angela and other with Gomes.

```
  pair  fname         lname        Culprit       time diff ...... other columns
   1    Adrian        Peter        Adrian           -2
   1    John          Adrian       Adrian            2
   2    Peter         Rusk         Rusk             -6
   2    Rusk          Anton        Rusk              6
   3    Angela        Gomes        Angela           -1
   3    Gomes         Angela       Gomes             1
```

From the above i know that in number 3 both Angela and Gomes are culprits. Time should also be sorted by ascending order.

Comment: Can you specify how Culprit is chosen for each new row? fname and lname are names of two people? To create a pair what should be matched: fname with lname or it can be fname with fname? I don't really understand what you doing here. Moreover, you should provide some code what you tried to do to get more attention for your question.

Comment: this is explained above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in love with this, there's probably a better way, but it works and doesn't use any python iteration / lists.

**Code:**

```
# Find and number the pairs and filter out the rows that don't belong
df = df.loc[(df['fname'].isin(df['lname'].shift())) | (df['fname'].isin(df['lname'].shift(-1)))].reset_index(drop = True)
df['pair'] = (df.index / 2.0).astype(int) + 1

# Find the culprit
df['culprit'] = df.loc[(df['fname'] == df['lname'].shift(-1)) | (df['fname'] == df['lname'].shift(1)), 'fname']
df.sort_values(by = ['pair','culprit'], inplace = True)
df.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)

# Calculate the time difference
df['time_diff'] = df.loc[df['pair'] == df['pair'].shift(1), 'ToE'] - df['ToE'].shift(1)
df['time_diff'] = df['time_diff'].fillna(df['time_diff'].shift(-1) * -1).astype(int)

# Sort
df.sort_values(by = ['pair','time_diff'], inplace = True)

print df[['pair','fname','lname','culprit','time_diff']].to_string(index = False)
```

**Output:**

```
pair   fname   lname culprit  time_diff
   1  Adrian   Peter  Adrian         -2
   1    John  Adrian  Adrian          2
   2   Peter    Rusk    Rusk         -6
   2    Rusk   Anton    Rusk          6
   3  Angela   Gomes  Angela         -1
   3   Gomes  Angela   Gomes          1
```